# Resize a webview embed inside scrollview

Tags: ios, sqlite, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a sqlite database of HTML strings that are songs.

**ViewController**
In this view controller I have a text and a button in which the user inputs the song number and a button to send the request to search the database.

**SongDisplay**
In this view controller I have a web view and a label both embed in a scroll view. The scrolling is disabled for my web view.

The lyrics display, and the scroll view resizes correctly. However the web view isn't being resized and is only displaying some of the lyrics. I know this because I have the scroll view and web view as different colours.

***Top of scroll view***
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hgpi8nlwnca0v8/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Aug%2022%2C%202013%2C%202.04.24%20PM.png

***Example of problem here, bottom of scroll view***
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8l8d82an613hec/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Aug%2022%2C%202013%2C%201.57.14%20PM.png

This is my code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;

    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

    frame.size = fittingSize;

    [self.scroll setContentSize:fittingSize]; //scroll is the name of the scroll view

    aWebView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"size: %f" ,fittingSize.height);
}
```

How do I get both the web view and scroll view to resize?

Comment: WebViews in ScrollViews do not work well. This will likely get better soon. Right now it's going to be problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself when OS X Mavericks was officially released. The problem before was probably a result of a bug in the beta releases.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by loading content inside `viewWillAppear` inside detailView
like this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self configureView];//<-- here i am call loadHTMLString
}

- (void)configureView
{

    // disabling scroll for webview
    if ([self.detailWebView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
        self.detailWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; // available starting in iOS 5
    } else {
        for (id subview in self.detailWebView.subviews)
            if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
                ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollEnabled = NO;
    }

    // setting content
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailTitle.text = self.detailItem->title;
        //image scaling styles
        NSString *style=@"<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "img { \n"
        "   display: block;"
        "   float:none;"
        "   margin:0 auto;"
        "   max-width:100%;"
        "   height:auto;"
        "} \n"
        "</style>\n";

        [self.detailWebView loadHTMLString:[style stringByAppendingString:self.detailItem->content] baseURL:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per per Apple's recommendation one should not embed webview inside scroll view

> Important
>
> You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView
>   objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch
>   events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Ref:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/